# Python % operator vs concatenation

Tags: python, concatenation, interpolation

When would it be preferable to use:

```
for n in range(0, 100):
    print "The count is "+str(n)
```

Vs.

```
for n in range(0, 100):
    print "The count is %d" % (n)
```

Or visa versa?

Comment: You should use `'{}'.format(n)`

Comment: @AntonProtopopov, can you elaborate?

Comment: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5082452/python-string-formatting-vs-format). Do you need only such simple substitution like that?

Comment: What do you mean by 'preferable'?

Comment: The first one will never be preferable. The creation of temporaries will make it slow.

Comment: `format` is the more general-purpose solution and code is cleaner, easier to read and more maintainable if you do the same type of things the same way. Doesn't casting and adding white space by concatenation look clunky?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `%d` syntax has been deprecated. Use `str.format` for string formatting.

Examples:

```
"My name is {0}.".format("Austin")
"I am {} years old and make ${:.2f} per hour.".format(50, 50.29999) # positional arguments
myDict = { "language" : "English", "major" : "Computer Networking" }
"I speak {language} and have a degree in {major}.".format(**myDict)
myList = [2, "German Sheppard", "Lucy", "Ethel" ]
"I own {} {}s named '{}' and '{}'.".format(*myList)
```

Read more about `str.format` [here](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html#str.format).